# CPLEX: How to solve same cplex "model" with different "data"

Tags: scripting, cplex, opl

After running the below code in *CPLEX OPL IDE*;

```
nmbl = 521466;
nbi = 5;

int As[nbi] =...;

int amb[nmbl] = ...;
dvar boolean I[nmbl][nbi];

minimize 
sum (a in nmbl, b in nbi, c in nmbl: c>a,d in nbi: d != b) I[a][b]*I[c][d]*10;


subject to 
{

**cons1:**
forall (i in nmbl)
    I[i][1] + I[i][2] + I[i][3] + I[i][4]+ I[i][5] == 1; 

**cons2:**

forall (j in nbi)
     sum (i in nmbl)
          I[i][j]*amb[i] <= As[j];
}
```

While running this code,I found an **CPLEX Error 1016**: *Promotional version. Problem size limits exceeded*.

Still if we want to solve the current problem using the same version of software.

If we provide 50 elements at a time as an input to the model.

- Since manually it is not possible because size of nmbl is too high an
  if we take 50 elements at time it would take **521466/50** iterations to
  do. Is there any way to iterate model for each 50 set of nmbl data?

Is there is any way to do it? I will be thankful to you if anybody can provide me small example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't see the point of that approach. If your problem really is separable into lots of disjoint sub-problems like that it might work. But from what you have told us about the problem it sounds like it is not separable like that. Just solving lots of little bits of the whole problem almost certainly will not work. Finding a feasible solution would be difficult. Getting a good solution would be very difficult.  Designing a decomposition approach for any large problem is complex and difficult and the likely convergence with such tiny sub-problems is going to be very slow. You will almost certainly need to get a bigger solver licence.